# Wrapping span tags inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of div tags nested within each other and a few span tags nested like below:-

```
<div id="leftcol">
    <div id="tagcloud">
        <span class="mytags"><a href="">tag1</a></span>
        <span class="mytags"><a href="">tag2</a></span>
        <!-- and a few more spans of the same type -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the issue is that spans overflow their container div tag. Can somebody be kind enough to let me know how to get these spans to be wrapped inside their container div (here the div with the id tagcloud). Both the outer divs have a width of 300px specified.

(Additional info- I have done a CSS reset using the YUI reset-fonts-grids. I am just getting accustomed with CSS.)
-The site can be looked at frekshrek.appspot.com... the tag cloud just does not wrap inside its container div

Comment: Posting your CSS would also help a lot.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try declaring `float: left;` on the `.mytagcloud` class. Something like:

```
.mytagcloud{
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    font-family: 'Reenie Beanie', arial, serif;
}
```

in your `basiclayout.css` file, line 71.

Comment: @rubic @Freek - you shouldn't use `margin: 5px;` on any floated element. In IE6, double float margin bug takes effect. I would stick with `padding: 5px;`, or `margin: 5px 5px 5px 0;`.

Comment: @orokusaki: the `margin` property was already in @rubicondude's CSS file, but thanks for the heads up. On the same note, are we seriously *still* supposed to be supporting IE6 ?

Comment: not sure this is still applicable... Doesn't work for me

Comment: @DavidBrossard floated elements still float, that hasn't changed in a very long time as it's a CSS 2.1 property and it's effectively supported by all browsers. There must be something else preventing it from working on your end.

Comment: As with CSS, there probably is :-) Thanks for the update. I think my issue is that the div's parent is a td that can grow inifinitely. No reason for the DIV to stop either then

Answer (score 39):

Other option is to just set your tags to be displayed inline-block:

```
.mytags {
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: **This solution is the way to go!** The accepted one uses `float: left` which is not necessary at all, and this one is more general and works in every scenario (for example, if you want to align the tags to the center...)

Comment: Also +1 to this answer, it appears to be the correct way to do it: no floats, no adding extraneous spaces between the spans (which wasn't an option in my particular case due to the need to support particular chrome extensions).  Thanks! jz

Answer (score 9):

You have no spaces between your spans, so the browser sees them  all as one single long word. If you add a single space or a line break between each span they will be treated as separate words and wrapped accordingly.

Comment: You can always edit your first answer and either add the update or replace the initial one completely. Helps keeping the answer section clean ;)

Comment: Would there be any other way as I am generating the span tags dynamically through a for loop ,on the server , enclosing them in a div and sending it . Cant figure out a way of adding spaces between them

Comment: In your for loop you could try adding '&nbsp;' immediately after the closing span tag. This is the html entity for a non-breaking space. So for example, the server should return something like: <span>...</span>&nbsp;<span>...</span>

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler to just add one line in the CSS file ?

Comment: I wont be able to do that Simon , as I am using some sort of html helpers there. Whatever I would have to do, would have to be in the CSS file.What Line are you talking of FreekOne. Would be really helpful, if something that like worked out!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are floating the spans inside the div container. If this is the case, and you want the 'tagcloud' to  contain (wrap) the floated spans then you need to clear the floats by adding the following to the tagcloud CSS:

```
div.tagcloud {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

An explanation of this technique can can be found here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Comment: No I am not floating the spans inside at all. The only css that applies there sets the width of the outer two divs and the font of the span tags. That is It. While the above solution helps to fit the span inside the div, it induces a scroll bar at the bottom. It does not wrap the span from one line to the other below when the width is about to be exceeded