# Spaces between generated HTML elements

Tags: gwt, html, space

I encountered a problem, simple but stupidly blocking.

I build a GWT (Google Web Toolkit) Web HMI.
In a panel, I create a bunch of `CheckBoxes`. Each of these gives me a `span` element which contains the `input` checkbox and its `label`. So far, so good.

So I get this :

```
<span class="blablabla keepUnited">blabliblu1</span><span class="blablabla keepUnited">blabliblu2</span><span class="blablabla keepUnited">blabliblu3</span><span class="blablabla keepUnited">blabliblu4</span>
```

In the generated HTML code, the `span` elements are stuck together. This messes up all my beautiful layout! The layout is fine if I separate the `span` elements with spaces:

```
<span class="blablabla keepUnited">blabliblu1</span> <span class="blablabla keepUnited">blabliblu2</span> <span class="blablabla keepUnited">blabliblu3</span> <span class="blablabla keepUnited">blabliblu4</span>
```

How to insert these spaces?

Comment: "I build a GWT Web HMI. In a panel, ..."  What sort of panel?

Comment: A FlowPanel. Which gives me a HTML `div` element.

Answer (score 4):

Extend FlowPanel so that it adds an inline space between widgets:

```
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlowPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.InlineHTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

public class MyFlowPanel extends FlowPanel {

  @Override
  public void add(Widget w) {
    if (w != null) {
      if (this.getWidgetCount() > 0) {
        super.add(new InlineHTML(" "));
      }
      super.add(w);
    }
  }

}
```

Use the new FlowPanel in the same way as the old FlowPanel:

```
public class MyMain implements EntryPoint {

  @Override
  public void onModuleLoad() {
    MyFlowPanel myFlowPanel = new MyFlowPanel();

    myFlowPanel.add(new CheckBox("Checkbox 1"));
    myFlowPanel.add(new CheckBox("Checkbox 2"));
    myFlowPanel.add(new CheckBox("Checkbox 3"));
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(myFlowPanel);
  }

}
```

Result has spaces (to test, I used a vertical bar '|' instead of a space ' '):

[image]

Not sure if the fact that the spaces are inside spans is a deal-breaker for you.  The real version ought to rework the method insert() as well.  Also note that with this approach, you have to be careful when checking widget counts or iterating through widget lists, since MyFlowPanel is secretly injecting InlineHTML widgets.  So after you've added two checkboxes, for example, there are three widgets in the flow panel.

If you really wanted to get fancy, you could add constructors to MyFlowPanel in which you specify what "interstitial" string, SafeHtml, or Widget you wanted added between your main elements.

Comment: Thank you, Steve.
I understand that this will not insert a lonesome space, but a space with its `span` shell.
I had thought of inserting manually inline elements like `Labels`. But this is a workaround, complicated and not elegant. So I prefer a clean solution, but if I don't find one, I'll go towards this workaround.
Overriding the `add` method is a good idea, it suppresses the need to add each spacer element manually ; that makes the workaround less complicated.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML (and GWT) does not care about the disposition of your element. It's the role of the [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets).

A solution will be to put a simple CSS class on each span element with the setStyleName or the addStyleName method

After that, in your css :

```
margin-right: 4px;
```

Of course, you can replace 4px by the value you want.

Comment: HTML cares about the space. In post-production, I tried with the space and my layout got displayed perfectly.

Comment: On the `span` elements, I have already put CSS spacings, like margin and padding. Much more than 4 pixels. And these spacings appear. Fine. But the absence of space between the `span` elements breaks my beautiful layout. In the page, which I view with Firefox, the `span` elements get stuck together. The absence of space forbids soft line break between the `span` elements. But I need such soft line break, because there is not enough width for everyone together ! Inserting a space between two `span` elements allows such line break - which is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is set `float:left;` on the span elements, as suggested in this stackoverflow answer: [Wrapping span tags inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797338/wrapping-span-tags-inside-a-div-css)
It's maybe not perfect and don't forget to add `clear:both` in the tag after the spans, otherwise you layout will break.

Answer (score -2):

you could try to run this simple search & replace regex

search:

```
</span><span
```

replace:

```
</span> <span
```

Comment: How ? Where ? I don't write the HTML code. I write Java classes, and GWT (Google Web Toolkit) generates the HTML food.